# How to get value from multiple SELECT tags (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value from each option I select h , but the jquery return the value for the first select only!.
I have no idea how to fix it.

```
  <select  id="Group" >
      <option value="">Select Group</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="1">d</option>
      <option value="1">d</option>
      <option value="1">d</option>
  </select>

  <select  id="Group" >
      <option value="">Select Group</option>
      <option value="2">1</option>
      <option value="2">d</option>
      <option value="2">d</option>
      <option value="2">d</option>
  </select>
```

Jquery code

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Group').change(function(){

            var group_id2 = $('#Group').val();

            alert(group_id2);
            $.ajax({
                url:"../include/ajax_process/doc_process.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{group_id:group_id},
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#employee').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things -

ID should always be unique, so you shouldn't have two elements on the page with the same ID. That said, let's assume you update this a bit and maybe use a class, for example -

`$('.group').change(function(){`

OK, now you want the value of the CHANGED element. You can do this by looking at the event

```
$('.group').change(function(e) {
  var data = $(e.target).val();
  // (etc do the rest of your code here)
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, Thant was a fast answer, I overlooked on that id can't used more than once.